# How to add publisher stuff into setup project

Tags: windows-installer

I've got a setup project. When It runs it says something like that

[image]

As I understand I suppose to add some kind certificate or something into it. Could you tell me how? I'd rather like not to see this dialog or at least it suppose to say something about publisher. Not 'Unknown' thing. I exactlty know who the publisher is :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can create your own certificate for testing purposes using sdk utilities:

Makecert.exe
Cert2spc.exe
signtool.exe

[.NET Framework Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9kh6s92(v=VS.80).aspx)